# How to convert this SQL Server formula to an Excel formula?

Tags: sql-server, excel, modulo

I have tried all day long but cant make it to work ...

```
    declare @a as nvarchar(max)
    declare @b as nvarchar(max)
    declare @c as nvarchar(max)
    declare @d as nvarchar(max)
    declare @k as integer

    set @b = '00115'
    set @d = '00001'
    set @c = '10000952010'

    select ((CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), CONVERT(BIGINT, @b + @d) % 97) + @c) * 100) % 97)
```

The result from this formula is 77

My Excel formula so far looks like this, but it's not correct

```
MOD(((MOD(11500001;97)+10000952010)*100);97)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is operator `+`. In SQL server "formula" it concatenates values, in Excel it sums values. Correct excel formula would be

```
MOD(((MOD(11500001;97)&10000952010)*100);97)
```

But then you get a "big number" problem with the `MOD` function. So the complete solution would be:

```
=MOD(MOD(((MOD(11500001;97)&10000952010)*100);134217728*97);97)
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you please write from where you get number 134217728

Comment: Look [here](https://excel.tips.net/T003302_Large_Numbers_in_the_MOD_Function.html)